# MySQL Installer update modify mysqldump call

Tags: mysql, installation, backup

I am trying to update my MySQL Server 5.6 to the latest version 5.6.43 using the MySQL community installer. But it fails.

On "Apply Configuration" there is this (new?) step "Backing up MySQL database" which always fails due to a missing option of the underlying mysqldump call. It needs to add the --max_allowed_packet=512M option to work.

How do I modify the call or how do I skip the complete backup step?

> Beginning configuration step: Backing up MySQL database
>   Starting MySQL Server in order to run the mysql_upgrade tool.
>   Warning: There may be some errors thrown by MySQL Server, the mysql_upgrade tool is going to be run next to attempt to fix database incompatibilities.
>   Starting process for MySQL Server 5.6.43...
>   Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" --console...
>   Process for mysqld, with ID 6280, has been started successfully and is running.
>   Successfully started process for MySQL Server 5.6.43.
>   2019-01-22 09:24:07 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
>   2019-01-22 09:24:07 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
>   2019-01-22 09:24:07 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.6.43) starting as process 6280 ...
>   Running mysqldump tool to backup the database...
>   Backup files will be dumped to "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\Backup\mysql_dump-2019-01-22T09.24.11.sql".
>
> Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump.exe --defaults-extra-file="C:\Users\Master\AppData\Local\Temp\404a41e4-6738-40af-b26d-cd2a3981776d.ini" --user=root --host=localhost --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --routines --events --single-transaction=TRUE --all-databases --result-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\Backup\mysql_dump-2019-01-22T09.24.11.sql"...
>   mysqldump: Error 2020: Got packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes when dumping table `table_test_attach_data` at row: 291
>   Process for mysqldump, with ID 5492, was run successfully and exited with code 3.
>   Ended configuration step: Backing up MySQL database

Answer (score 1):

As I found out for myself you can make a step back in the installer and uncheck the backup step.

As a result one need to make a manual backup if not taking the risk of loosing everything in case of an error in the update procedure.